# Grouping the rows of a text file based on 2 columns

Tags: shell, command-line

I have a text file like this:

```
1  abc 2
1  rgt 2
1  yhj 2
3  gfk 4
5  kji 6
3  plo 4 
3  vbn 4
5  olk 6
```

I want to group the rows on the basis of first and second column like this:

```
1  abc,rgt,yhj 2
3 gfk,plo,ybn 4
5 kji,olk 6
```

such that I can see what are the values of col2 for a particular pair of col1, col3.
How can I do this using shell script?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it :

```
awk -F " " '{ a[$1" "$3]=a[$1" "$3]$2","; }END{ for (i in a)print i, a[i]; }' file.txt | sed 's/,$//g' | awk -F " " '{ tmp=$3;$3=$2;$2=tmp;print }' |sort
```

Answer (score 0):

Just using awk:

```
#!/usr/bin/env awk -f

{
    k = $1 "\x1C" $3
    if (k in a2) {
        a2[k] = a2[k] "," $2
    } else {
        a1[k] = $1
        a2[k] = $2
        a3[k] = $3
        b[++i] = k
    }
}
END {
    for (j = 1; j <= i; ++j) {
        k = b[j]
        print a1[k], a2[k], a3[k]
    }
}
```

One line:

```
awk '{k=$1"\x1C"$3;if(k in a2){a2[k]=a2[k]","$2}else{a1[k]=$1;a2[k]=$2;a3[k]=$3;b[++i]=k}}END{for(j=1;j<=i;++j){k=b[j];print a1[k],a2[k],a3[k]}}' file
```

Output:

```
1 abc,rgt,yhj 2
3 gfk,plo,vbn 4
5 kji,olk 6
```